# Plotting a list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, plot, data-structures, graph

I have data contained in a list of lists. For example

```
> head(balance)
[[1]]
 [1]  99 101 102 103 102 100 104 103 101  97 105 104 106 107 106 104 100  92  76  44

[[2]]
 [1]  99 101 100 102 103 104 103 101  97  89 105 106 107 106 108 109 108 106 102  94  78
[22] 110

[[3]]
 [1]  99  97 101 102 103 102 104 105 106 107 108 109 108 106 110

[[4]]
 [1] 101 102 101 103 104 105 106 107 108 107 105 109 110

[[5]]
 [1]  99 101 100 102 101  99 103 104 105 104 106 107 106 104 108 109 110

...
```

I want these `balance` values to make up the y-axis of my graph, and their index to make up their x-values. I want each sublist to be it's own line on the graph.

Using the function call

```
plot(unlist(betIndex), unlist(balance), type = 'l')
```

I am able to obtain the following plot. It looks like the lines are connecting between the sublists, which is not what I want. I want each sublist to be it's own line. How could I go about this?

For reference, `betIndex` is just the index of the values. I made it for plotting purposes.

[image]

Comment: We don't really want to type in your data.  Please provide your sample  by running `dput(head(balance))` and pasting the result into your question.

Comment: @G5W list(c(99, 101, 102, 103, 102, 100, 104, 103, 101, 97, 105, 104, 
106, 107, 106, 104, 100, 92, 76, 44), c(99, 101, 100, 102, 103, 
104, 103, 101, 97, 89, 105, 106, 107, 106, 108, 109, 108, 106, 
102, 94, 78, 110), c(99, 97, 101, 102, 103, 102, 104, 105, 106, 
107, 108, 109, 108, 106, 110), c(101, 102, 101, 103, 104, 105, 
106, 107, 108, 107, 105, 109, 110), c(99, 101, 100, 102, 101, 
99, 103, 104, 105, 104, 106, 107, 106, 104, 108, 109, 110), c(101, 
102, 101, 103, 104, 103, 101, 105, 106, 105, 103, 99, 91, 75, 
107, 108, 109, 110))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data that you provided, you can make a blank plot with sufficient range to include all of the lines, then use `lines` to plot each. I am coloring each line differently to keep them separated.

```
xmax = max(unlist(lapply(balance, length)))
ymin = min(unlist(balance))
ymax = max(unlist(balance))

plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,xmax), ylim=c(ymin, ymax), ylab="")
for(i in seq_along(balance)) {
    lines(balance[[i]], col=i) }
```

[image: Multiple lines from a list of lists]